# Is it possible to setup environment variables within noses setup.cfg

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I'm working with a fairly sprawling embedded python project. At the moment the tests is hidden behind a make invocation which sets up PYTHONPATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH on the workstation so the tests can complete. Is it possible to specify this within the nose configuration so that the user need only invoke *nosetests* in the directory?

Otherwise should I just include some boiler-plate in the test files to manipulate the required paths?

Comment: Reading further it looks like I need to setup a test fixture that gets run before my tests. However the nose documentation doesn't seem to have any clear examples on this.

Comment: create a runtests.sh file that sets the environment up and then calls `nosetests`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: that's what I'm trying to avoid. It's mainly a convenience thing as IDEs seem to be geared to just running nosetests directly.

Comment: If you're manipulating the PYTHONPATH it sounds like you have bigger problems than just setting up your test environment properly

Answer (score 1):

No nose does not have any current ability to set environment variables from a config file:

```
def _configTuples(self, cfg, filename):
    config = []
    if self._config_section in cfg.sections():
        for name, value in cfg.items(self._config_section):
            config.append((name, value, filename))
    return config

def _readFromFilenames(self, filenames):
    config = []
    for filename in filenames:
        cfg = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
        try:
            cfg.read(filename)
        except ConfigParser.Error, exc:
            raise ConfigError("Error reading config file %r: %s" %
                              (filename, str(exc)))
        config.extend(self._configTuples(cfg, filename))
    return config
```

Any configuration options specified from a configuration file will be stored directly as tuples in a list. In fact if you tried passing some values that nose did not accept then it would throw an error.

```
def _applyConfigurationToValues(self, parser, config, values):
    for name, value, filename in config:
        if name in option_blacklist:
            continue
        try:
            self._processConfigValue(name, value, values, parser)
        except NoSuchOptionError, exc:
            self._file_error(
                "Error reading config file %r: "
                "no such option %r" % (filename, exc.name),
                name=name, filename=filename)
        except optparse.OptionValueError, exc:
            msg = str(exc).replace('--' + name, repr(name), 1)
            self._file_error("Error reading config file %r: "
                             "%s" % (filename, msg),
                             name=name, filename=filename)
```

See the part where you get a NoSuchOptionError.

You do have one option that I've dabbled with a little; using [nose-testconfig](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-testconfig/) which allows you to specify test configuration options in some kind of file where nose **will not** throw an error if your values are unrecognized.

Or you can just throw some **@setup** or **@teardown** methods into your tests. I would be very wary of adding any kind of setupTests.sh script, as this only adds an extra layer of complexity to run your tests.